# pygame.quit() hangs, even outside IDLE

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using Pygame 1.9.1 with Python 2.7.3 on Debian,

I am trying to get a small test program working before I get any more advanced;
Things seem to work fine up until the point where I tell Pygame to quit.

I've read that you need `pygame.quit()`, at least inside IDLE (to make sure it quits cleanly,)
So I've got that - but **it still froze**.

The relevant code looks something like this:

```
def mainLoop():                                                                                                                 
    running = True                                                                                                              
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()                                                                                                 
    while running:                                                                                                              
        gameMode()                                                                                                              
        render()                                                                                                                
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()                                                                                          
        for event in pygame.event.get():                                                                                        
            if event.type == QUIT or key[K_ESCAPE]:                                                                             
                running = False                                                                                                 
                print 'finished'                                                                                                
                return                                                                                                          
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__=='__main__':                                                                                                        
    mainLoop()                                                                                                                  
    print 'exiting after main loop'                                                                                             
    pygame.quit()
```

I run this and it prints out both 'finished' and 'exiting after main loop',
but even then hangs with the window still present.

Even more strangely,
I've pared it down to a minimal program that **still hangs (that's this, in its entirety):**

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.quit()
```

Could someone shed some light on what's going on here?

Comment: Your test program doesn't hang for me. What operating system are you on?

Comment: Debian Linux, 32-bit (3.2.0 kernel).

Comment: Forgot to mention - this is Python 2.7.3 and Pygame 1.9.1, so as far as I can tell, I'm up to date.

Comment: [1] outside of idle you don't need to call `pygame.quit()`. It happens automatically [2] Won't work outside because you don't `import pygame` [3] Try running this: http://code.google.com/p/ninmonkey/source/browse/boilerplate/pygame/1.%20blank%20screen/1%20-%20basic.%20pygame.py

Comment: try just using `sys.exit()`. ideally you should make your own custom exit function that cleanly saves and finishes all open event threads.

Comment: Both the boilerplate code, unmodified, and using sys.exit() in place of pygame.quit() cause Python to lock up the same way. Once the program is supposed to quit, it locks up - not even Ctrl-C will kill it at that point - and I need to kill -9 the whole Python process.

Comment: what about replacing `pygame.init()` with `pygame.display.init()`

Answer (score 5):

`pygame.init` will try to initialise all of PyGame's modules, whether needed or not. `pygame.quit` will quit all active modules, and is called automatically when the interpreter quits (which is why the issue still remains when the explicit call to `pygame.quit` is removed).

The `pygame.mixer.quit` method currently hangs on Debian Wheezy (as of 2013-06-12). If you are not using the mixer, you can just replace calls to `pygame.init` with calls to the `init` methods of the modules which you are using (a list of modules which require `init` calls can be found under 'I' in the [PyGame documentation index](http://www.pygame.org/docs/genindex.html#I)). In my case, initialising the `display` module was sufficient. So, your example becomes:

```
import pygame
pygame.display.init()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Also hangs on Arch! But this is a solution to the problem!

Comment: I was only using pygame for the joystick while using pyside for GUI. This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The command `pygame.quit()` basically just closes the window that you have open.  The code will then continue until it reaches an error, which will be the screen not existing.  If you want to actually stop the program, use `sys.exit()` and the program wil stop.

Comment: I've tried using sys.exit() in place of pygame.quit() and it still hangs.

Comment: @BJYackley make sure you're using both.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to run the program in IDLE? ive heard you are not suppose to do that since IDLE does not like pygame

Comment: I'm not using IDLE - this is a straight-up text editor, followed by running the test program from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

even when using IDLE, I did both:

```
# other code ^
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

and that seemed to work